# multi task learning with ImageDataGenerator

Tags: keras, deep-learning

I am training a model with one input (an image) and 2 outputs, in order to use ImageDataGenerator with one output the folder containing the data needs to have a specific form. My question is can we use ImageDataGenerator  with multi task learning and if so how should the data be organized in the folder?